# Noty (notification library) is not defined - AngularJS Web Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, defined, noty

I currently am in the process of making an AngularJS web application from scratch and am new to AngularJS, which is important to note because I could always be missing something fundamental.

**The issue is this:**

I have installed the Noty library (`npm install noty`) and wrote code for a simple Noty dialog:

```
var confirmSubmit = new Noty({
    text: 'Your feedback has been submitted!',
    buttons: [
        Noty.button('Close', 'btn btn-default', function() {
            confirmSubmit.close();
        })
    ]
});
```

This code is inside a working, already integrated JavaScript file other than the main app.js. Format:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('JStest-reviews', []);
    ...
})();
```

However, when I launch the web application in Chrome, I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Noty is not defined
```

The official documentation (https://ned.im/noty/#/installation) has little to no description of what is needed aside from installing Noty and creating a Noty object. I have tried using other statements provided in the installation documentation like:

`import Noty from 'noty';` or `const Noty = require('noty');` before the object creation, but none have resolved the error.

Since my web app was made from scratch, a package.json file was not automatically created, and I wonder if code is needed in there to make this work (right now my manually created one just has name, version, etc. info).

---

**Thank you in advance for suggestions/solutions**

I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: How are you loading scripts into the page? Are you using a bundler like Webpack or Browserify?

Comment: I load it in the index.html file head tag like: <script type="text/javascript" src="reviews.js"></script>. Noty was just included via npm.

Comment: Ok, and have you also added `<script src="path/to/noty.js"></script>`?

Comment: I have not. I'll try that now.

Comment: `/path/to...` was just an example, you need to work out what the actual path is

Comment: Gotcha, I was importing the script exactly like the documentation said: `<script src="lib/noty.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` when I needed to make it a custom path. Looks like the error is gone. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Approximate answer given by @Phil:**

Noty script inclusions should contain the actual path to the Noty library files.

e.g. for me, the fix was:

```
<link href="node_modules/noty/lib/noty.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="node_modules/noty/lib/noty.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

instead of just:

```
<link href="lib/noty.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="lib/noty.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(From official documentation https://ned.im/noty/#/installation)